# Android - TableView with ScrollView (not TableRow)

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout with 2 columns and dynamic number of TableRows. Each row is represented by a TextView (1st column) and a ExpandableListView (2nd column).

I have the TableLayout defined in my layout xml without rows. Rows are created in a dynamic way by java code (activity).

I would like to do a scrollView on my TableLayout and not on each TableRows (this is whats happening now).

When i expand all ExpandableListViews (and total size of my table goes bigger than my activity layout) i only have a scroll bar on the last expandableListView, and not even on the last row.

How can i scroll the Table and not the row or the expandableListView?

layout.xml:

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: where is that ExpandableListView you are mentioning here?

Comment: @KrzysztofDubrowski ExpandableListView is created dynamically on activity, for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`, the same goes for nested ListViews and any nested scrollable containers.

Comment: but what do i want to scroll is the TableLayout and not the ExpandableListView it self.

Comment: then you will have to work it out in a different way, I am afraid, the `ExpandableListView` is a scrollable view and you will experience problems nesting... There is a problem with checking which view to scroll. If you implement the part you are using the ExpandableListView for yourself, you will see the TableLayout scrolling.